# grouping array data using a field value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have an array newsfeed containing last followers of current user, as follows:

```
$newsFeed=array(
1 => array(
'follower'=>'1',
'following'=>'5',
'datecreation'=>'2013-07-12 15:10:34'
),
2=>array(
'follower'=>'6',
'following'=>'5',
'datecreation'=>'2013-07-12 12:30:56'
),
3=>array(
'follower'=>'7',
'following'=>'5',
'datecreation'=>'2013-05-12 19:08:00'
)
);
```

What I want to do, is to shorten the news feed, puting items of the same day in one array , item 1 and 2 in the previous table. As follows:

```
 $newsFeed=array(
    1 => array(
    'follower'=>array('1','6'),
    'following'=>'5',
    'datecreation'=>'2013-07-12'
    ),
    3=>array(
    'follower'=>'7',
    'following'=>'5',
    'datecreation'=>'2013-05-12 19:08:00'
    )
    );
```

Notice that in the result, I dropped the array with key=2 and key=1, and I put the followers' ids in an array, that I put in a new array.

Is there a PHP function that can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, this is a suggested one ... More edits may come in the future regarding possible errors or exceptions.

This is my suggested solution

```
$creationDate1 = false;
        foreach ($newsFeed as $key => $feed) {

            /*             * **followers** */
            if ($feed['type'] == 'follow') { //test if the current row is a follow type
                $creationDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $feed['creationdate']);
                $creationDate = $creationDate->format('Y-m-d'); //drop H:i:s from date

                if ($creationDate != $creationDate1) {  
                    $followKey = $key;
                    $followersArray = array();
                }


                $followersArray[] = $feed['follower']; //array for followers ids


                unset($newsFeed[$key]);//remove the current row

                if ($creationDate != $creationDate1) { // if follow has not the same date as the previous one


                    $newsFeed[$followKey] = array(
                        'follower' => $followersArray,
                        'following' => $feed['following'],
                        'creationdate' => $feed['creationdate']
                    );//add row, with the datetime
                } else { //add row, with date, and without time.
                    $newsFeed[$followKey] = array(
                        'follower' => $followersArray,
                        'following' => $feed['following'],
                        'creationdate' => $creationDate
                    );
                }

                $creationDate1 = $creationDate; //$creationDate1=date of the current row.
            }
        }
```

Any improvements, as well as edits or suggestions will be appreciated